# why get all results of jq in a single array element in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to get all results of jq query in a array in bash, but it gives me all results in the first array element.
Could you help me? I would like to having every result in one array element

```
bash-4.2$ try=$(tm run jobs:status::get -s "tm=serverA&work=*&status=Failed" | $PATH_API/jq -r '.statuses[].name // empty')
bash-4.2$ echo $try
job_B job_C
bash-4.2$ echo "${#try[@]}"
1
bash-4.2$
```

Comment: `variable=$(command)` creates a **string** variable, not an array.

Comment: ...btw, using `declare -p try` instead of `echo $try` will provide a more unambiguous readout of the variable's value. With your current value it should emit `declare -- try="job_B job_C"`; with a real array it would be `declare -a try=( [0]=job_B [1]=job_C )`

Answer (score 0):

If the status names are sufficiently uncomplicated, you could add an extra pair of parentheses:

```
try=($(tm run ....))
```

(Consider also invoking jq without the -r option.)

Otherwise, you could consider using `readarray`, or other techniques for initializing bash arrays.

Comment: Please don't advise that -- see BashPitfalls #50.

Comment: I thought the proviso would be warning enough...

Comment: Better to show a good-practice approach rather than a known antipattern. As an example that works even with the older bash releases Apple ships: `read -r -d '' -a try < <(tm run ... && printf '\0')` -- even has a compelling advantage over the modern `readarray` approach insofar as it passes a nonzero exit status through (by emitting the trailing NUL, which causes `read` to return nonzero if the pipeline returned nonzero).